# Complex script for bulk/update a document without getting it

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I have for my project, this ES mapping representation :

```
- BOOK
    - label: String,
    - active: Boolean
    - total_term_occ: Long

- TERMS
    - label: String,
    - ngram: Byte,
    - tot_occurrences: Long,
    - books [{
        - id: String,
        - label: String,
        - occurrences: Long,
        - tfidf: Double
    }]
```

For each new term (ex: "ES rocks"), I want to :

```
- Update the total occurrence in the "TERMS" doc
OR 
- Create the new term if not exists
AND (if term already exists)
- BOOK :
    - Create a new object if the book does not already exist with "occurrences" to 0 and "tfidf" to NULL
    OR
    - Update the "occurrences" field if the book exists (with a loop ?!)
```

I want to make a bulk request "update -> script -> upsert" but without getting the document before updating it.

Do you think this is possible with the choice of mapping ? I can't find a good solution....